# How to draw a spring?

Tags: graphics, animation

I am new to *Mathematica* and have recently been exploring graphical animations. So I was experimenting with simple concepts in periodic motion and hence wondered how can I draw a simple spring? Is there an easier/better way to do this?

The solution I arrived at was a simple function to draw a spring between two $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

```
hspring[a0_, x10_, x20_] := 
 Module[{a = a0, x1 = x10, x2 = x20, n = 100},
  h = (x2 - x1)/n;
  xvalues = Table[k, {k, x1, x2, h}];
  yvalues = Table[a Sin[m Pi/2], {m, 0, n}];
  Line[Transpose @ {xvalues, yvalues}]
 ];

vspring[a0_, y10_, y20_] := 
 Module[{a = a0, y1 = y10, y2 = y20, n = 100},
  h = (y2 - y1)/n;
  yvalues = Table[k, {k, y1, y2, h}];
  xvalues = Table[a Sin[m Pi/2], {m, 0, n}];
  Line[Transpose @ {xvalues, yvalues}]
 ];

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{hspring[0.2, 0, Abs[2 Sin[x]]], Red, PointSize[0.03], 
   Point[{Abs[2 Sin[x]], 0}]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-1, 1}}], 
  {x, 0.01, 2 Pi, 0.1}]
```

[image: Horizontal spring]

[image: Vertical Spring]

Comment: Look here http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SimpleHarmonicMotionOfASpring/

Comment: or here: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SimpleSpringMassDamping/

Comment: I was surprised that there is no Spring[] build in function in Mathematica Graphics actually. There should be form 3D and 2D. For dynamics and mechanical demos, it will be useful to have one with many options to use.

Comment: It would be nice to have procedures that can take the spring's endpoints as a parameter. So that they can be used as 'graphics primitives' to draw complex pictures or animations. Something in the form: `spring[{P1_,P2_}, styleOptions___]`, with P1 and P2 coordinates of the endpoints in 2D or 3D space (overloading can be used). Please keep your old solutions, some users might find them faster and thus more useful than others.

Comment: With this number of beautiful solutions it is possible to start a "Miss Spring 2014" competition.

Answer (score 51):

A textbook-like animation

```
turns = 10;  
aa = Table[Framed@ 
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[
          Piecewise[{{{1, x, 0}, x <= 0}, 
                    {{Cos[2 Pi turns x/r], x, Sin[2 Pi turns x/r]}, 0 < x <= r}, 
                    {{1, x, 0}, x > r}}], 
        {x, -.5, r + .5}, 
        PlotStyle  -> {Gray, Specularity[Gray, 10]}, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
        PlotPoints -> 100,  MaxRecursion -> 3, 
        PlotRange  -> {{-10, 10}, {-1, 15}, {-5, 5}}, 
        Axes       -> None,  Boxed -> False, Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 30}, 
        ViewPoint  -> {10000, 1, 5}] /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.2, rest],
     Graphics3D[Sphere[{1, r + 1, 0}, 1.25]]], {r, Table[15/2 - 5/2 Cos@x, {x, 0, Pi, .1}]}];
Export["C:\\test.gif", Join[aa, Reverse@aa]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, With `PlotPoints -> 4 turns + 1, MaxRecursion -> 0` it looks better, especially for a big number of turns :)

Comment: Line join should be rounded to make it looks better.

Comment: Finally something that looks like a spring! :)

Comment: Now it even has SHM.+1

Answer (score 19):

In 3D you can use a spiral:

```
spring3D[height_, n_, opts___] :=
 ParametricPlot3D[
   {Cos[n 2 Pi t], Sin[n 2 Pi t], height t},
  {t, 0, 1},
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
  opts]
```

[image: spiral]

Comment: A tubular variant can be seen here: http://www.davidaltherr.net/mathematics/notebooks/mass_spring_one_d/mass_spring_one_d.php . Is it me or your version is highly non-uniform? I mean the coils at the moving end are unwinding much faster then those at the fixed end.

Comment: @Peltio Strange perspective I suppose, [projected version](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0roqQ.gif)

Comment: of course, it is in a 3D box! (Facepalm)

Answer (score 18):

I propose a bit more compact solution:

```
spring[r_: {1, 0}, n_: 20, w_: 1] := Line@Transpose[{r, -Cross[r]}.{(# - 1)/(2 n), 
      Re[I^#] w/Norm[r]}] &@Range[2 n + 1];
```

Here `r` is the vector of the spring. The default value `{1, 0}` corresponds to the horizontal unit-length spring. `n` is the number of half-waves and `w` is the width of the spring.

You can play with it with `Locator`:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[spring[r], PlotRange -> 5], {{r, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Notes:

1. `Cross[r]` rotates `r` by 90 degrees.
2. `{r, -Cross[r]}` is the rotation transform.
3. Instead of `Re[I^#]` you can use `Sin`, `TriangleWave`, etc.

Answer (score 16):

The drawings by @Peltio reminded me of the way my high school teacher drew coils so I have opted for faking the 3d effect. Essentially, a squinted cycloid curve loos like a coil under perspective:

```
With[{stretch = 2, revs = 8}, 
 ParametricPlot[{.1 stretch ((2) t revs - 
       Sin[2 π t revs + π/2]) + .1 stretch, (1 - 
     Cos[2 π  t revs + π/2])}, {t, 0, 1}]]
```

[image: coil]

which is OK, but the lines crossing ruins the 3D effect. A way to amend that is by generating a set of allowed ranges for the parameter along the cycloid and wrapping the whole thing in a function:

```
    coilFunc[revs_, stretch_, t_] := 
 Block[{range, gap = .055, gapPos = 1.12, plhold},
  range = {{0, gapPos - gap}}~Join~
    Table[{i + gapPos + gap, i + gapPos - gap + 1}, {i, 0, revs}];
  range = range/revs;
  If[Or @@ ((#1 < t < #2) & @@@ range), 
      {.1 stretch ((2) t revs -  Sin[2 π t revs + π/2]) + .1 stretch, 
      (1 -  Cos[2 π  t revs + π/2])}]
  ]
```

the values of the parameters `gap` and `gapPos` are what I found aesthetically pleasing. Now, you can play with it:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{ParametricPlot[coilFunc[8, 2 + Sin[g], t], {t, 0, 2}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick,
   PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, All}]}]
 , {g, 0, π}]
```

[image]

but to properly fake 3d, one needs to amend the `ColorFunction` appropriately. So the following is the above code with the added option 
 `ColorFunction -> {Hue[1 - 3 Mod[.1 - #3, 1/8] ] &}]`. I call it "the psychedelic spring":

[image]

Comment: +1 Beautiful. And the Psychedelic spring actually fits well in the '60s era that gave birth to those books :-). Can you give a version that accepts general 2D points for the extremes?

Comment: I might be a couple of days but yep, I'll edit in an improved version when I find the time.

Answer (score 14):

This is yet another way of doing it, albeit not as elegant as ybeltukov's.
My mind is simple and I try to do one step at the time. So, here is a unit spring with `n` coils and 'aspect ratio' (width with respect to the unit length) `h`:

> ```
> unitSpringPoints[n_, h_] := Block[{dl, xlist, ylist}, 
>     dl = 1/(2  n + 1);
>     xlist = Flatten[{0, 1.5 dl, dl Table[k, {k, 2, 2 n - 1}], 1 - 1.5 dl, 1}];
>     ylist = Flatten[{0, 0, h/2 Table[(-1)^(k + 1), {k, 2, 2  n - 1}], 0, 0}];
>     Transpose[{xlist, ylist}]
>   ]
> ```

This is a spring connecting `{0,0}` and `{1,0}` with two small horizontal segment at the end points (that is the reason for generating two separate lists). 
To show the spring just wrap a Line around the generated points, like this

```
Show[Graphics[Line[unitSpringPoints[5, 0.25]]]]
```

Next I defined a function to transform coordinates in order to produce a spring between two given points `{x0,y0}` and `{x1,y1}`. Since this is very old code, I defined my own transformation matrix as in

> ```
> coordinateTrasformMatrix[{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}] := Block[{theta},
>     theta = ArcTan[x1-x0,y1 - y0];
>     {{Cos[theta], -Sin[theta]}, {Sin[theta], Cos[theta]}}
> ]
> ```

(EDIT: I incorporated a suggestion received on MMA SE to use the two-arguments form of `ArcTan` in orderd to avoid `Indeterminate` results for the case `x0==x1`).
And then I used it to transform the coordinates of the points of the the unit spring in those of the points of the spring between the given points

> ```
> coordinateTransform[coords_List, {{x0_, y0_}, {x1_, y1_}}] := Block[{scale, mat},
>     scale = Sqrt[(x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2];
>     mat = coordinateTrasformMatrix[{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}];
>     ({x0, y0} + mat .({scale, 1}*#)) & /@ coords
>     ]
> ```

Then, a spring with `n` coils and aspect ratio `h` between points `{x0,y0}` and `{x1,y1}` would be given by

> ```
> spring[{{x0_,y0_},{x1_,y1_}},n_:8, h_:.25]:=
>       Line[ coordinateTransform[ unitSpringPoints[n, h], {{x0, y0}, {x1, y1}}]]
> ```

For example:

```
Show[ Graphics[ spring[{{2, 2}, {3,3}}, 5, 0.25] ], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Sample animation (not tested, adapted from old code):

```
Do[ Show[ 
        Graphics[ spring[{ {2, 2}, {3 + .5Cos[t], 2 + .8Sin[t]} }] ], 
        AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {1, 5}}
    ], {t, 0, 6.3, .1}
]
```

---

**Some wishing**

Back then I planned to replicate the shape of the springs shown in Crawford's "Waves", the third volume of the Berkeley Physics series

[image: Crawford's springs]

(I really liked the way springs are drawn there). I planned to act on the unit spring to produce the minimal set of points required for a fast but smooth interpolation, but never found the time to complete it. Perhaps someone - who knows how springs are drawn in Craword's "Waves" has a more straightforward and (possibly) elegant solution for that.

And, since we are at it, here is another spring shape I find very visually appealing. Those from Alonso and Finn's "Fundamental University Physics"

[image: Alonso Finn's springs]

It would be nice to turn this post (the OP's) in a resource of code to draw springs in various styles (from essential to stylish or presentation-ready) and computational load (because if one wants to model a series of say 40 coupled pendulums to see how an exponential wave develop, you need something fast to draw).

Comment: I don't have a copy of Craword's at hand. Could you post an image?

Comment: @belisarius, done. I believe this falls under the 'fair use' for educational purpose.

Comment: @belisarius, wow, that was fast! I cannot see it right now but - if I may add some other constraint - can your procedures be recoded in 2D only (not by looking at the 3D box from a particular perspective, but by drawing in a Graphics and not Graphics3D container?

Comment: Take a look at the last animation in my answer :)

Comment: @belisarius - Amazing! But what happened to the comment with your other code? Please do not discard any solution: some users might find certain answers more useful. Another thing to improve this post in general: it would be nice to have procedures that can take the spring's endpoints as a parameter. So that they can be used as 'graphics primitives' to draw complex pictures or animations. (I'll duplicate this comment in the original post so that new posters will see this as a possible addition to their code)

Comment: The user that made the [suggestion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13034) was Peeter Joot. My reasons for rejecting are also shown on that page.

Comment: @rm-rf thanks, I will give him due credit in the body of the post in my next edit (I have a few modifications and enhancements in mind, plus, I have to add an animation or two).

Answer (score 8):

Here's a version, that like Peltio's takes vector end points, but uses a Sin[] curve, and has an optional fraction drawn as a line.

```
ClearAll[spring]
spring::usage = "spring[ point1, point2, numberOfTurns, height, fractionToDrawAsLinesAtEnds ]" ;
spring[ a1_List, a2_List, n_: 8, h_: .25, f_: 0.1 ] := Module[{n1, d, nd, r, r1 },
  n1 = Norm[a1] ;
  d = a2 - a1 ;
  nd = Norm[d] ;
  r = RotationMatrix[ArcTan @@  d ] ;
  r1 = r . {n1, 0} ;
  ParametricPlot[
   {
    {a1 - r1 + r . { n1 + nd f + t (1 - 2 f) nd, h Sin[ 2 Pi n t]}},
    {a1 - r1 + r . { n1 + nd f + (1 - 2 f) nd + t f nd, 0}},
    {a1 - r1 + r . { n1 + t f nd, 0}}
    }
   , {t, 0, 1 }
   , Epilog -> { Point[{a1, a2}]}
   ]
  ]

spring[ {1, 2}, {3, 5} ]
```

[image: spring]

Comment: I've been using your above code in Mathematica 9, but recently upgraded to Mathematica 11.  Now nothing appears and I am very new in trouble shooting.  Do you have any suggestions how to adapt this for Mathematica 11?

Comment: The sample above works for me with Mathematica 11.2.0.0

Answer (score 7):

Here's the 2D curly one wrapped up like a graphics primitive.

```
Spring2D[start_, end_, loops_, radius_] := 
 Module[{detail = 40, steps}, steps = detail (loops + .5); 
  Translate[
   Rotate[Line@
     Table[{radius + (Norm[end - start] - 2 radius) a/steps + 
        radius Cos[2 Pi a/detail + Pi], 
       radius Sin[2 Pi a/detail]}, {a, 0, steps}], {{1, 0}, 
     end - start}], start]]

Manipulate[
 Graphics[Spring2D[p1, p2, loops, radius], 
  PlotRange -> 5], {{p1, {-2, 0}}, Locator}, {{p2, {2, 0}}, 
  Locator}, {{loops, 8}, 4, 20, 1}, {{radius, .5}, .2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty and easy to implement.

Answer (score 2):

I typically use the "raw" Graphics and Graphics3D functions because it's easier to combine multiple objects that way.  If you simply want a quick and dirty way to produce the point set for drawing a squiggly (Sin) line betwee two arbitrary points, this may be of use. The number of turns is intended to be an integer.  Making it negative reverses the orientation of the coils.

```
Clear[springPoints]
springPoints::usage = 
  "springPoints[radius, \
numberOfTurns,numberOfPoints][{x0,y0},{xL,yL}]";
springPoints[r_, n_, \[Rho]_][P0_, PL_] := Module[{tHat, nHat, L},
  L = Norm[PL - P0];
  tHat = Normalize[PL - P0];
  nHat = {-tHat[[2]], tHat[[1]]};
  P0 + tHat L # + r Sin[#  n 2 \[Pi]] nHat & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/\[Rho]]
  ] 

Clear[Ps10, Ps1L, Ps20, Ps2L, \[CapitalDelta]P, r, n1, n2, \[Rho], \
s1, s2]
r = .25; \[Rho] = 100;
Ps10 = {0, 0}; Ps1L = 5 {1, 1}; n1 = 8;  
Ps20 = Ps1L; Ps2L = Ps20 + Ps1L; n2 = -10;
\[CapitalDelta]P = {-1, Sqrt[2]}; 
s1 = springPoints[r, n1, \[Rho]];
s2 = springPoints[r, n2, \[Rho]];
Graphics[{
  {Dashing[.002]
   , Line@s1[Ps10, Ps1L]
   , Line@s2[Ps20, Ps2L]}
  , {Line@s1[Ps10, Ps1L + \[CapitalDelta]P]
   , Line@s2[Ps20 + \[CapitalDelta]P, Ps2L]}
  , Point[{Ps10, Ps1L, Ps20, Ps2L, Ps1L + \[CapitalDelta]P}]
  }]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modify Peeter Joot's code to include the case when f (length of end of spring) is zero:

```
...
If[f>0,
    ParametricPlot[ ... ],
    ParametricPlot[a1-r1+r.{n1+nd f+t (1-2 f) nd,h TriangleWave[n t]},{t,0,1}]
]
```

After modification, you can make arbitary curve a spring:

```
pts3 = Table[{t, t^2}, {t, -1, 1, 0.1}];
tuples = Partition[pts3, 2, 1];
final = Map[(spring[#[[1]], #[[2]], 3, 0.02, 0][[1, 1]]) &, tuples];
Plot[-t^2, {t, -1, 1},
    Epilog -> Line[Flatten[Cases[final, _Line, Infinity] /. Line -> Identity, 1]],
    PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, 
    AspectRatio -> 0.8*GoldenRatio
]
```

[image: zigzag]