# Improving a jagged Tube[ ] edge

Tags: plotting

While trying to improve [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37219/193) answer of mine, I found it difficult to get a smoother edge.
Any ideas?

```
turns = r = 10; 
ParametricPlot3D[
  Piecewise[{{{1, x, 0},  x <= 0}, 
             {{Cos[2 Pi turns x/r], x, Sin[2 Pi turns x/r]}, 0 < x <= r}, 
             {{1, x, 0}, x > r}}], {x, -.5, r + .5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Gray, Specularity[Gray, 10]},
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-1, 15}, {-5, 5}},
  Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {10000, 1, 5}] /. 
 Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.2, rest]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: did you turn on antialiasing? it looks smooth on my computer

Comment: @halmir Yup. However, perhaps it isn't working for some reason. If somebody else confirms your comment I'll look deeper into it. Thanks!

Comment: In my MMA version 8 on Mac, it looks exactly like what you show in the question. But in version 10, it looks like someone left it in the bathtub too long: [all wrinkly](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Bti.png)... so in other words, on version 10 (Mac) I don't think I can even begin to help in any way because the problem is deeper than antialiasing.

Comment: To avoid the atrocious look I see on version 10 Mac, I would get rid of the replacement `Line -> Tube` and simply add `Tube[0.2]` to the `PlotStyle` options instead, combined with `Exclusions -> None`.

Comment: @Jens Thanks a lot. I'm running v9 on Win32. The v10 wrinkled image is outrageous :)

Comment: I think there are actually two different problems here : 1/ **smooth edges**, 2/ **smooth shading**. 1/ I can reproduce your edges problem with OSX, v9&v10.0.1 only if I set **off** the antialiasing in the Preferences Menu. 2/ I confirm @Jens smooth shading problem in OSX(v10 only), I get exactly the same wrinkly tube, but it is independent of the antialiasing setting in the pref. menu. (notice that that the edges of the tube are smooth in @Jens image -> antialiasing is on). However I've found this shading problem goes away If I reduce the viewpoint distance like `ViewPoint -> {50, 1, 5}]`.

Comment: This  shading problem disappears also if I set the **`Graphics3DRenderingEngine`** option in OptionInspector to `BSPTree` or `Software`, however each graphics rendering becomes very very slow and finally it crashes the kernel. The get the smoothest shading @Jens solution (Tube in PlotStyle) is the best.

Comment: I have found an `Antialiasing` option in the Option Inspector (v9&v10) which seems (v10 only) to modify the graphics rendering independently of what has been set in the Preferences Menu ... ? Maybe you can try it or the others options in `RenderingOptions` folder ...

Comment: @SquareOne Antialiasing is on here, and it doesn't help. The same also after setting,  `PlotStyle -> Tube[.2]`

Comment: @belisarius Yes, `PlotStyle -> Tube[.2]` only modifies the shading problem not the edges problem.  I noticed these are two different problems. Now, why don't you have smooth edges with antialiasing on ... ???

Comment: @SquareOne Well, I don't know. Perhaps someone on WinXX (and Mma v9 if possible) could confirm if this is a "localized" problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playing with many options, I find that to remove the jagged edges from the tube, the best solution is to Rasterize with high ImageResolution (which is probably not what you want). Using `Antialiasing` alone did not do as well a job, but it was still better than the image shown. Here is what I get in windows 7, V 10.02

```
turns = r = 10;
Rasterize[Style[
  Graphics3D[First@ParametricPlot3D[
      Piecewise[{{{1, x, 0}, x <= 0}, {{Cos[2 Pi turns x/r], x, 
      Sin[2 Pi turns x/r]}, 0 < x <= r}, {{1, x, 0}, x > r}}],
      {x, -.5, r + .5},
      PlotStyle -> {Gray, Specularity[Gray, 10]},
      Lighting -> "Neutral",
      PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-1, 15}, {-5, 5}},
      Axes -> None, PlotPoints -> 1000, ImageSize -> 600,
      Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {10000, 1, 5}
      ] /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, .2, rest], Boxed -> False], 
      Antialiasing -> True], ImageResolution -> 240]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using `Antialiasing -> True` alone:

```
turns = r = 10;
Style[
 Graphics3D[First@ParametricPlot3D[
     Piecewise[{{{1, x, 0}, x <= 0}, {{Cos[2 Pi turns x/r], x, 
     Sin[2 Pi turns x/r]}, 0 < x <= r}, {{1, x, 0}, x > r}}],
     {x, -.5, r + .5},
     PlotStyle -> {Gray, Specularity[Gray, 10]},
     Lighting -> "Neutral",
     PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-1, 15}, {-5, 5}},
     Axes -> None, PlotPoints -> 1000, ImageSize -> 500,
     Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {10000, 1, 5}
     ] /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, .2, rest], 
     Boxed -> False], Antialiasing -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Changing `Mesh`, `PlotPoints` and such options had no effect on the jagged problem.

Comment: You're right about `Rasterize[]`. I would rather prefer not to use it :). The second try is nearer (in fact I tried it before posting) but for some reason it displays far worse on my front end (another Mma version, windows version, whatever). Thanks a lot!