# Why does my Animate crash?

Tags: bugs, animation, predictive-interface

I am having trouble with Animate.
For no reason I can discern, my animation stop running, again and again, just about 1.5 seconds after the evaluation get started.
Even with slight changes to the code, it still stops.

I am using *Mathematica* V10.3 on Windows 7 OS.
And the computer system has enough spaces in the memory (8 GB).

My code is very simple.
I just want to animate the motion of a spring.
What is wrong with this?

```
spring[length_, radius_, n_] := 
   Module[{t = 0}, 
     ParametricPlot3D[
       {length t, radius Cos[n 2 Pi t], radius Sin[n 2 Pi t] + 1}, 
       {t, 0, 1}, 
       Boxed -> False, 
       Axes -> False, 
       PlotStyle -> {Gray, Thickness[0.015]}]];
Animate[
  Show[
    Graphics3D[{Polygon[{{0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 2}, {0, -2, 2}}]}], 
    spring[time, 0.5, 10]], 
  {time, 0, 5}]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT//
Solved!
This was solved by inactivating the checkbox, "Suggestions bar after last output" in the Preferences.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash on OS X with Mathematica 10.3.1.  What exactly do you mean by crash?  Is it the front end or the kernel that crashes?  If the former, it may be related to your graphics drivers (just a hunch), since the animation is a 3D one.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, Windows 10x64 with Mathematica 10.3. Try to close "Show Suggestions Bar ..." in Preferences before you run the animation.

Comment: This works for me on Win 7 Pro 64bit with 10.3

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37207/how-to-draw-a-spring

Comment: @Szabolcs I mean the kernel crashes while video animate is going. Animate stops suddenly and the kernel goes into a infinite loop mode.

Comment: @rewi@Edmund My computer's system is very neatly organized. I don't understand the reason why only my system has the problem. I am using Windows 7 64bit Home Premium and there is no virus or any errors on the system.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the kernel crashes" precisely (or what you mean when you say that "the kernel goes into infinite loop mode")?  Use screenshots if necessary. I worry that we may not all be using the word "crash" the same way.

Comment: @Szabolcs Let me clarify it in a detailed way as following. When I put Shitft+Enter at the input cell where there is the animate code, the animate graphic is created. But almost as soon as it is created, the animate stops and Mathematica does nothing and starts to be lagging, showing the alert message in the screenshot image I added in the post. I am Korean, so you can see some Korean letters but they are irrelevant.

Comment: @SmartHumanism Thanks for the clarification, the screenshot helps.  This is not what is usually called a crash, so I removed that word from your post to avoid confusion. It might be some sort of performance problem.  Can you check the CPU usage of both Mathematica.exe and any WolframKernel.exe processes?  There will be at least two WolframKernel.exe processes, can you check both?

Comment: Additionally, can you try the following: disable the suggestions bar and disable the Korean annotations.  [These two boxes should be unchecked.](https://www.evernote.com/l/AIdy0gDCn0RKH5sfIteG-TN681KY9-TA3Vc)  Restart Mathematica (not just the kernel, but the front end too), and try again. Is the problem still there?

Comment: @Szabolcs I am looking for how I can disable suggestion bars and Korean annotations. Would you tell me a bit about how to do it? It is not being seen. :)

Comment: I added the screenshots of pu usage while it has problem ongoing. And the cpu usage was very low. And the cpu is Intel's i5 3570.

Comment: If you click the link in my previous comment, it brings up a screenshot showing what boxes to uncheck in the preferences.

Comment: @Szabolcs It has been solved! Yeah~! Thank you for the so much help, I really am extremely thankful to you! After I did Preference settings that you told me to do, the problem has gone away! You helped too many times on this matter that has been really bothering me and I really appreciate it. What a shame that I cannot express the appreciation fully in English to you because I am not good at English so there is so heavy limitation to the extent I can express my feelings.

Comment: @SmartHumanism Can you please check which checkbox solved it?  Was it the (Korean) annotations or was it the suggestions bar?  Either way, these should not affect the `Animate` performance, so this is a bug.  Can you also report it to Wolfram support?

Comment: @Szabolcs Right now I will check it. I will do it! Thank you for the huge help.

Comment: Actually I just realized that I can also turn on captions (in Korean or any other language) in my English version Mathematica.  The problem is caused by the suggestions bar, not the captions.  You can turn the captions back on safely.

Comment: The check box that is related to the cause of the bug is "Show Suggestions Bar after last output". The check box, "Show code captions(non-English languages only)", does not seem to affect it. It was the suggestions bar!

Comment: @Szabolcs Yeah~! You're right!

Comment: @Szabolcs  I upvoted all your comments and accidentally the first one was undone. Anyway thanks so much and I am writing the bug report to the technical support of the Wolfram site as you told me to do.

Comment: Glad your problem was solved. Please don't forget to accept the answer that helped you most, by clicking on the check mark on its left side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by the Suggestions Bar.  I can reproduce the issue on OS X if I turn the Suggestions Bar on.  I believe this is a bug.

To work around the issue, please permanently disable the Suggestions Bar as described here:

- http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12406

(Hiding it temporarily may not work.)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that you specify the step size in the [`Animate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Animate.html) and use a fixed [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html). I also recommend that you pull the definition of the [`Polygon`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html) outside of the `Animate` since it doesn't change.

```
spring[length_, radius_, n_] :=
  Module[
   {t = 0},
   ParametricPlot3D[
    {length t, radius Cos[n 2 Pi t], radius Sin[n 2 Pi t] + 1},
    {t, 0, 1},
    Boxed -> False,
    Axes -> False,
    PlotStyle -> {Gray, Thickness[0.01]}]];

Module[
 {poly =
   Graphics3D[{
     Polygon[
      {{0, -2, 0}, {0, 2, 0},
       {0, 2, 2}, {0, -2, 2}}]}]},
 Animate[
  Show[
   poly,
   spring[time, 0.5, 10],
   PlotRange ->
    {{0, 5}, {-2, 2}, {0, 2}}],
  {time, 0, 5, .05}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice. I will try it in a short time.