# Fix the dimensions in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d

Starting from what is read [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154024/animate-a-spring/154026#154026), write the following code:

```
spring[r_, x1_, x2_] := Module[{m, n},
    xvalues = Table[m, {m, x1, x2, (x2 - x1)/1000}];
    yvalues = Table[r Sin[n Pi/2], {n, 0, 100, .1}];
    zvalues = Table[r Cos[n Pi/2], {n, 0, 100, .1}];
    Line[Transpose@{xvalues, yvalues, zvalues}]] /. Line -> Tube;

x[t_] := 10 Cos[t]
tmax = 15;
xmin = NMinValue[{x[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t];
xmax = NMaxValue[{x[t], 0 <= t <= tmax}, t];

Magnify[
 Graphics3D[
  {
   spring[.2, xmin - .1, x[0]],
   {LightGray, Sphere[{x[0], 0, 0}, .3]}
  },
  Axes -> {True, False, False},
  Boxed -> False,
  ImageSize -> {200, 200},
  Lighting -> "Neutral",
  PlotRange -> {{xmin - .1, xmax + .1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
  PlotRangePadding -> 1,
  ViewPoint -> Above],
1.5]
```

you get:

[image]

Unfortunately, if I choose `x[t_] := Cos[t]` the result would be the following:

[image]

So the question is as follows: how can I do so to make the size of the graphic representation always equal and only change the x-axis scale?

Thank you!

Comment: Inside `frames` you have to specify a fixed `ImageSize`. In addition to that (also inside `frames`) you should set `ViewVertical` (to control magnification) and `PlotRangePadding`.

Comment: Try `AspectRatio->1/4` (inside `frames`)