# 2D Torsional Spring

Tags: animation, drawing

I need help to draw an animated circular 2D spring. I'd like to define the spring like `Spring[x_, y_, θ0sx_, θ0dx_, θsx_, θdx_]`, where:

- `x` and y are the coordinates of the centre of the spring
- `θ0sx` is the initial open angle of the spring, measured from vertical (if positive, the spring is open counterclockwise) to `sx`
- `θ0dx` is the initial open angle of the spring, measured from vertical (if positive, the spring is open counterclockwise) to `dx`
- `θsx` and `θdx` are the equations governing the 2 sides angles of torsional spring.

Then I'd like to use it in `Manipulate` to change variable `t`, in the form:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  Spring[0,0,-90,+90,θ1[t],θ2[t]],
  ],
 {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: diagram]

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37207)?

Comment: Yes, i tried to use that, but i don't know how use and modify like my request. I found this code: sp[x_, y_, a_, t_] := {x + (1 + 0.2 Cos[a t]) Cos[t], 
   y + (1 + 0.2 Cos[a t]) Sin[t]};
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  sp[0, 0, 40/tt, t],
  {t, 0, tt},
  Axes -> None,
  PlotRange -> {-4, +4}
  ],
 {{tt, Pi}, 1*10^(-14), 2 Pi}
 ]