How to use Mathematica to plot following helix solid geometry?

So, can you provide a method to plot this geometry in mathematica? It is soild instead of a surface. I need it to be printed out from mathematica as stl. document.
I have tried with Code "RegionProduct" method, but I do not know why it cannot work.
So, can you provide me a method to form in mathematica?
Thanks very much!

Answer is here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37219

@MichaelE2  Please note that the OP is soild instead of a surface.

@cvgmt How to plot a solid? How to make a solid in Graphics3D? For instance,Export["/tmp/foo.stl",   ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u] Cos[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[u]}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi + 3 Pi/4}]] In other words, I don't see the significant distinction between a solid and the boundary of a solid for the use-case`at hand. An STL file specifies only the surface of the solid.

@MichaelE2 Before I post my answer,I have read the author's comment in another answer,the solid should get the Volume, that is why I deliberate seal the two end to get a real solid.

Again, the volume of a solid is defined by its boundary, a surface. Why doesn't the question mention volume?

@MichaelE2 Sure. But the boundary must be Closed instead of only Show the pieces of surfaces ( BoundaryDiscreteGraphics not always work for such Show)

@MichaelE2 Please test ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u]  Cos[v], Sin[u]  Sin[v], Cos[u]}, {u, 0,     Pi}, {v, -Pi, Pi + 3  Pi/4}] // BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics

Method-1

We build several circles along the helix curve with normal be the tangent of the curve, and then using OpenCascadeShapeLoft to thread the circles to get the solid.

Clear["Global`*"];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"];
ω = 10;
r = .5;
thickness = .05;
f[t_] := {r*Cos[ω*t], r*Sin[ω*t], t/4};
circles = 
  Table[OpenCascadeCircle[{f[t], f'[t]}, thickness], {t, 
    Subdivide[0, 2   π, 61]}];
s = OpenCascadeShape /@ circles;
loft = OpenCascadeShapeLoft[s, "BuildSolid" -> True];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[loft, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"AngularDeflection" -> 0.15}];
reg = BoundaryMeshRegion[bmesh];
Volume[reg]
Graphics3D[{MaterialShading["Aluminum"], reg}, 
 Lighting -> "ThreePoint", Boxed -> False]


0.245232


Method-2

Another way is directly construct a BoundaryMeshRegion from the data of the plot.
In the plot, we set MaxRecursion -> 0.
In the plot,we set two meshs to as the the boundary of such tube and construct two polygons to seal the two openings of the tube.

ω = 10;
r = .5;
thickness = .05;
f[t_] := {r*Cos[ω*t], r*Sin[ω*t], t/4};
{tangent, normal, binormal} = 
  Last[FrenetSerretSystem[f[t], t]] // Simplify;
F[t_, θ_] := 
  f[t] + thickness*{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} . {normal, binormal};
plot = ParametricPlot3D[
   F[t, θ], {θ, 0, 2  π}, {t, 0, 2  π}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> {40, 800}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#5 &}, Mesh -> {{0, 2  π}}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive@{Thick, Red}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
    Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}];
pts = Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest__] :> pts, -1][[1]];
polys = Cases[plot, GraphicsGroup[data_] :> data, -1][[1, 1]];
lines = Cases[plot, _Line, -1];
reg = BoundaryMeshRegion[pts, 
  Polygon[Join[lines /. Line[pts_] :> Rest@pts, First@First@polys]]]
Volume[reg]


0.245702


Method-3
ω = 10;
r = .5;
thickness = .05;
f[t_] := {r*Cos[ω*t], r*Sin[ω*t], t/4};
{tangent, normal, binormal} = 
  Last[FrenetSerretSystem[f[t], t]] // Simplify;
F[t_, θ_] := 
  f[t] + thickness*{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]} . {normal, 
       binormal} // Evaluate;
ptss = Table[
   F[u, θ], {u, Rest@Subdivide[0, 8, 2001]}, {θ, 
    Rest@Subdivide[0, 2 π, 51]}];
{m, n, p} = Dimensions[ptss];
bm = BoundaryMeshRegion[
  Catenate[
   ptss], {Table[
    Polygon[{{#1[[1]], #2[[1]], #2[[2]]}, {#1[[2]], #1[[1]], \
#2[[2]]}}] & @@@ 
     Thread@{Partition[Range[1, n] + j*n, 2, 1, 1], 
       Partition[Range[1, n] + (j + 1)*n, 2, 1, 1]}, {j, 0, m - 2}], 
   Polygon[Range[1, n]], Polygon[Range[1, n] + (m - 1)*n]}]
bm // Volume



It's always nice to see good usage of OpenCascadeLink. Would you mind if I used this example in the documentation?

@user21 Your are welcome! Thanks!

The simplest way making such a helix is using pack of joint Regions.
pts = N@Table[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 15, 0.1}];
br = BooleanRegion[Or,
                   Table[
                     Cylinder[pts[[i;;i+1]], 0.1], 
                     {i, 1, Length@pts - 1}]
                  ];
rrr=Region@br


Volume@rrr

0.409727

but here are some gaps seems. Does it OK? Will it cause any break or deformation when I import this helix.stl file into other software?

This is the result of usage of the discrete approach. Generally, you can make it smoother setting the step of u smaller. It is not a break because the most part of helix is connected. This is like a set of scratches on the outer surface of the spring

Oh, I got it. Thanks very much. Very helpful

Then, can the method of using "RegionProdut" be OK? I have tried, but the circle disk cannot sweep along the helix curve; I do not know why. Does it mean this method does not work?

@HingCu, The RegionProduct makes 3D shape from 2D using orthogonal translation mechanism. It does not help you with curved shapes like a helix.

myHelix =ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/20}, {u, 0, 40},
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
  PlotStyle -> Gray, PlotRange -> All] /. 
 Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.1, rest]


Export[".../myHelix.stl", myHelix, "STL"]

If you want a SOLID form:
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/20}, {u, 0, 40},
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False,
  PlotStyle -> Lighter[Gray], PlotRange -> All] /. 
 Line[pts_, rest___] :> {EdgeForm[None], 
   Cylinder[Partition[pts, 2, 1], 0.1]}


does the is a solid geometry with Volume? I have given the code "Volume" to the geometry "myHelix", why does it indicate wrong?

Is there any method to transfer closed surface into a solid geometry?

How about using the method of "RegionProduct"?

I have used "Volume" for the generated geometry, but why there is no value?

Simplest:
 R = 5; r = 0.3;
    g1 = ParametricPlot3D[{R Sin[t], R Cos[t], t/8}, {t, 0, 10 Pi}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Green, Tube[r]}, PlotRange -> All]
   
    Export[Drive\Path\"FEDER.stl", g1]



BoundaryDiscretize Graphics[g1] cannot be improve to a smooth solid if we use Plot Style->Tube

With STL files 3d printed jobs for ( r<< R ) are found to be  already reasonably smooth  solid helices.

can you add volume actions? since originally, I do it in this way, but I find in the center, the helix is hollow in the center.

and it is easy to be broken of the geometry when it is used in other software
